# Do you pronounce the t in ''et un/une'' ?

Tags: prononciation

I learned that the t is pronounced in ''est un/une''.

Does the same rule apply to ''et un/une'' ?

Answer (score 4):

Les liaisons sont distinguées en trois groupes : obligatoires, facultatives et interdites.
Après *et* la liaison est interdite.

> Ils ont une fille et un garçon (pas de liaison).

https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm

Attention ! Indication du pluriel (avant et)

- portes et fenêtres (pɔʁt-ze-fənɛtʁ)

Comment: In my understanding, there's actually a rules saying there shouldn't be any liaison after 'et'.

Comment: @Claire Oui, c'est interdit.