# in the phrase 'nous avons acheté' is the 's' sound in 'avons' pronounced?

Tags: prononciation

in the phrase 'nous avons acheté' is the 's' sound in 'avons' pronounced? Or is the 's' sound in 'avons' silent? I tried using Google Translate pronunciation but I couldn't quite make the sound difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No native speaker. I think that the first "liaison" (i.e. between *nous* and *avons*) is obligatory.
The sound z is produced: nuz‿avɔ̃.

The second "liaison" (i.e. between *avons* et *acheté*) belongs to the so-called facultative "liaisons". Some natives will make the "liaison", that is, they will produce the sound z as: nuz‿avɔ̃z‿aʃte but I tend to believe most of them will not make this "liaison", at least in colloquial French.

See the recent question:

[Do you pronounce the t in ''et un/une'' ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42002/do-you-pronounce-the-t-in-et-un-une/42003#42003)

and the references therein.

Comment: For me, native speaker, the two « liaisons » must  be made. The only difference I see is that in « nous avons », there will never be a delay between the two words, and between « avons acheté », it could be a little delay. After the delay, the « liaison » can be (should be?) omitted. In conclusion nous avons without liaison will be weird for a native speaker, but avons acheté will sound OK with or without liaison.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French) does not list the second liaison as obligatory.

Answer (score 1):

The second liaison is *not* obligatory in "Nous avons acheté". The first one is.